# Computing hash of file with OpenSSL gives different results depending on chunk size

Tags: hash, openssl

I want to generate a hash of a file with openssl.

```
CFile file;
CFileException fileException;
file.open(filename, CFile::modeRead, &fileException);
file.SeekToBegin();
unsigned char buffer[1024];
SHA_CTX context;
SHA1_Init(&context);
while(unsigned int bytesRead = file.Read(buffer, sizeof(buffer)) > 0)
{
    SHA1_Update(&context, buffer, bytesRead);
}
unsigned char hash[SHA_DIGEST_LENGTH];
SHA1_Final(hash, &context);
```

It seems to work, but if I change the chunk size, I get different results in hash. What's going wrong here?

Greets

Comment: `unsigned char hash[SHA_DIGEST_LENGTH);` : you close that with a square bracket in your actual code, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the problem:

`while(unsigned int bytesRead = file.Read(buffer, sizeof(buffer)) > 0)`

This works as:

`bytesRead = ( file.Read(buffer, sizeof(buffer)) > 0 )`

and not

`(bytesRead = file.Read(buffer, sizeof(buffer))) > 0`.

Comparision is higher priority than assigment.  Adding another set of paranthesis will solve your problem.  See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_operations#Programming_languages